# Deploy web application using Cargo plugin to remote server

Tags: java, maven, glassfish, payara

I'm trying to use Maven Cargo plugin to deploy war to a remote Payara server with this plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>glassfish5x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <payara.username>${payara.username}</payara.username>
                        <payara.password>${payara.password}</payara.password>
                        <payara.hostname>${payara.hostname}</payara.hostname>
                        <cargo.remote.username>${payara.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>${payara.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                        <cargo.glassfish.admin.port>4848</cargo.glassfish.admin.port>
                        <cargo.hostname>${payara.hostname}</cargo.hostname>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
            <!-- provides JSR88 client API to deploy on Payara Server -->
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.deployment</groupId>
                    <artifactId>deployment-client</artifactId>
                    <version>5.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Problem I am getting errors:

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.7.3:redeploy (default-cli) on project server: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-mav
en2-plugin:1.7.3:redeploy failed: Deployment has failed: null
```

What could be missing or wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Also, how to set the "context" by which the war will be deployed? What parameter or configuration to set?

Comment: Is there anything in the logs of Payara Server you are running against? Have you also checked that the Payara instance is running?